# Angular 4 Master/Detail service communication between children components

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have 2 child components within parent component, childA and childB act as master/detail.

[image]

I am using a shared service that get data from webAPI, and these children use this shared service to get the data.

**api/messages** - get all messages/Master

**api/messages/1** - get 1 message with the id/Detail

Child A which is master using a service to displays the list of messages in the view. api/messages returns all messages, each message has an id.

Now when I click in the master list on the message, I am able to get the ID of the message and save it to a variable in Master component.
Now the problem is how to display a message detail in detail component when message clicked in master component. I tried passing ID to a service but it doesn't work

Message Service Shared:

```
export class MessageService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getMessages(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('/api/messages').map(data => data)

}



getMessageById(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('/api/messages/3' ).map(data => data)
```

//the id 3 should be coming from master component and pass that id.

```
}
}
```

Master component: displays list of messages in the list

```
  emails: any[];

    constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }


  ngOnInit() {
   this.messageService.getMessages().subscribe(data => this.emails = 
   data.messages);

    }

    }
```

Detail components

```
   message;


    constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {
   }


    ngOnInit() {
    this.messageService.getMessageById().subscribe(data => this.message = 
 data);

  }

 }
```

Comment: also just passing the id to a child component will not work. It should pass the id to a child and fire a function in detail component maybe showdetail(3) in child component...but how to do it only when its pressed in master component

Comment: you can call API when ID is being set in child component, basically you can just add a setter in which you may check what is the ID being set to and call API from there, updated my answer as well, Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elegant solution would be to use the Subject pattern (which is a type of observable), to communicate between components and services.

Subject pattern Example:

Service that handles messages:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    sendMessage(message: string) {
        this.subject.next({ text: message });
    }

    clearMessage() {
        this.subject.next();
    }

    getMessage(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

App Component that Receives Messages:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import { MessageService } from './_services/index';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
    message: any;
    subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {
        // subscribe to home component messages
        this.subscription = this.messageService.getMessage().subscribe(message => { this.message = message; });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        // unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

[Subjects Reference](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject)

A more advanced pattern would be to implement [Redux](https://github.com/angular-redux/store) in your application.
The key ideas of Redux are this:

- All of your application’s data is in a single data structure called the state - which is held in the store
- Your app reads the state from this store
- This store is never mutated directly
- User interaction (and other code) fires actions which describe what happened
- A new state is created by combining he old state and the action by a function called the reducer.

You can read more about Redux in this detailed [Redux Reference with examples](http://blog.ng-book.com/introduction-to-redux-with-typescript-and-angular-2/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17998041)

Comment: @nyedidikeke thanks for the suggestion. I updated my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

you can have a `@Input` property in your detail component, and can change that based on what is selected in your Master component.

something similar to below,

```
 <detail [id]='<id coming from list>'></detail>
```

call API when ID is being set,

```
private _id: string = "";
  @Input()
  get Id(): string {
    return this._id;
  }
  set Id(id: string) {
    if (this._id !== id) {
      this._id = id;

      // call API
    }
  }
```

now you may pass the id from master list as an event from master list component.

Comment: what do you mean by child to child, can you give an example?

Comment: Using @Input we usually can pass from Parent to Child. In my case I have 2 childs within a parent components. <root-app><child1></child1><child2></child2></root-app>

Comment: @OleksandrFedorov, there are various ways you may have component to component interaction, you can read it in detail [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction), Cheers!!

Comment: @OleksandrFedorov, the way i described above is known as Mediator pattern, where interaction is being done by a common parent, so if you have a parent component to mediate you may use this technique, having said that if your component goes deep in another component, it becomes difficult hence we use Service where you can pass these info in a service and from there you may pass data around.